# How to bind an object to view in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a webform project but I mostly have background in MVC.
Is that possible to bind an object to a web form view (aspx) like it could be done in MVC instead of having data bind separately ? and why ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'binding an object to a webform'? Where does it compare to in MVC?

Answer (score 1):

If they are relatively simple controls like `Label`s, `TextBox`es, you just access their `.Text` properties to set them.

For more advanced controls, like the `GridView`, they have a `.DataSource` property which you can assign any object to, and cater for the binding in the ASPX.

--

> and why ?

ASP.NET web forms was designed to allow Windows Developers to move to Web Development easily. Also ASP.NET Web Forms was developed long before ASP.NET MVC. The lessons learned from the Web Forms platform were used as a basis for the development. These include:

- Allow unit testing
- Remove ViewState / ControlState dependency
- Allow the view to become separate from the code behind. In ASP.NET Web Forms, you *know* its a `TextBox`. In MVC, you don't
- MVC has targeted actions. Web Forms always require a `Page_Load` before any code occurs.
- Web Forms only allow 1 form tag. MVC can have as many as you want.

There are many other differences, but the point to take away is MVC is an overhaul of how ASP.NET Web Forms works.

Answer (score 0):

Not really...

You can bind items to various controls such as a List to a GridView or Repeater which you can then set render/update/deletes/inserts against but there's no out of the box Form-Class binding.

The traditional way is with a big save button and a this sort of statement

```
this.MyObject.Value1 = Value1Textbox.Text;
```